# Распознавание русских символов с изображений jpg, bmp, png

Tags: c#, .net, library, распознавание-символов

Подскажите библиотеку для распознавания русских символов с изображения, и возможностью использования в приложениях .Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract - просто загрузите русские шрифты